# Ruby syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I'm working on a simple ruby application just to try Ruby out. Now the idea was to create some tree of names and display those, however I get the following error and I don't understand why

`syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input`

This is my code

```
class Tree
    attr_accessor :children, :node_name

    def initialize(name, children=[]) 
        @children = children
        @node_name = name
    end

    def visit_all(&block)
        visit &block
        children.each {|c| c.visit_all &block}
    end

    def visit(&block) 
        block.call self
    end 
end

ruby_tree = Tree.new( "Ruby", [Tree.new("Reia"), Tree.new("MacRuby")] )

puts "Visiting a node"

ruby_tree.visit {|node| puts node.node_name} puts

puts "visiting entire tree"

ruby_tree.visit_all {|node| puts node.node_name}
```

Comment: Number of line (the whole error message) would be rather helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

This line was messing with my head. The puts doesn't belong there are all!

```
ruby_tree.visit {|node| puts node.node_name} puts
```

Comment: How does that provide any information that my answer doesn't?